# Looking for the land cargo equivalent of a "stevedore"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

A stevedore is someone who loads/discharges cargo from the docks.   I'm looking for equivalent of this occupation for inland cargo "dischargers/unloaders".

Comment: *Cargo Handler* / *Freight Handler* ?

Comment: Yep, *Freight Handler*:  (from a CareerBuilder job posting): *The Freight Handler loads, unloads, and transports freight within or near the terminal, yard, or work site.  Loads and unloads freight and counts onto or from pallets, trays, racks and shelves.
Loads freight into vehicles and installs blocking, bracing, or padding to prevent shifting or damage in transit.
Transports freight from storage dock area or trailers to designated area.*

Comment: Is stevedore the same as longshoreman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented already, *freight handler* is the term. If you google around, you'll get a ton of job postings using it.